# Style Trigger for different images and border background

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I Want to use different *Border Background* and Different Images (each image must use different background color)
how i change use *StyleTrigger* to do it ? (Now it just show red border for all images)

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="18" Height="18" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Red">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="High">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/project;component/Images/High.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="Medium">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/project;component/Images/Medium.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="Low">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/project;component/Images/Low.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you have given BorderBrush red for the border on the image... that is why red border coming for every image.. triggers will just update the Source of image.. not its border

Comment: @nit i want to know how i must use trigger for both border and images?

Comment: like the style you have give to Image.. similarly you will have to apply style triggers to the border to change its BorderBrush and Background

Comment: @nit , you mean i need two Trigger ? i need to combine these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Binding` is correct, you just need to add a similar `Style` to the `Border` to update the `Background` property and remove the `Background` value from the `Border` itself:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="18" Height="18" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="High">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="Medium">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="Low">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Image Width="16" Height="16">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="High">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/project;component/Images/High.png" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="Medium">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/project;component/Images/Medium.png" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.DataContext.my}" Value="Low">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/project;component/Images/Low.png" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Try this.

Comment: Sheridan, images has no background property. this is the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention... we can set the `Background` of the `Border` instead... I'll update my answer.